# Insert org.json.JSONArray into jackson ObjectNode

Tags: java, json, jackson

I have got stuck trying to insert a `JSONArray` into a Jackson `ObjectNode`. This is what I am trying to do:

```
public void myMethod(JSONArray jsonArray) {
    ObjectNode payload = objectMapper.createObjectNode(0);
    payload.put("array", /* jsonArray */);
    payload.put(/* some other things */);
    ...
}
```

It feels like something really silly but what is actually the best way to do it?!

EDIT: I am sorry beacause I did not mention an important point, that is I have to serialize the `ObjectNode` once I finished building it, so using `putPOJO()` is not a possibility.

Comment: What's wrong on putting `payload.put("array", jsonArray.toString());`?

Comment: Won't it just put it inside the `"array"` field as a string instead of as a json array?!

Comment: Exactly. It will store the string representation of your JSONArray.

Comment: Ok but I need the `"array"` field to be an actual json array not a string... I don't think it is equivalent, right?!

Comment: Then use the `putPOJO` method: `payload.putPOJO("array", jsonArray);`.

Comment: What does the `putPOJO()` method do? It has no documentation.

Comment: You can find the documentation in the following [link](https://fasterxml.github.io/jackson-databind/javadoc/2.7/com/fasterxml/jackson/databind/node/ObjectNode.html).

Comment: Could you add it to a Hashmap, and then serialize the Hashmap with Jackson?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I like [aribeiro](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1346996/aribeiro)'s approach more.  You can use the `putPOJO()` method to do this.  For example:

```
// Incoming org.json.JSONArray.
JSONArray incomingArray = new JSONArray("[\"Value1\",\"Value2\"]");

ObjectMapper objectMapper = new ObjectMapper();
ObjectNode payload = objectMapper.createObjectNode();
// Adds the JSONArray node to the payload as POJO (plain old Java object).
payload.putPOJO("array", incomingArray);

System.out.println(objectMapper.writeValueAsString(payload));
```

Javadoc can be found [here](https://fasterxml.github.io/jackson-databind/javadoc/2.7/com/fasterxml/jackson/databind/node/ObjectNode.html#putPOJO(java.lang.String,%20java.lang.Object)).

Note: here's a previous implementation that I submitted using `readTree()`:

```
// Incoming org.json.JSONArray.
JSONArray incomingArray = new JSONArray("[\"Value1\",\"Value2\"]");

ObjectMapper objectMapper = new ObjectMapper();
ObjectNode payload = objectMapper.createObjectNode();
// Reads the JSON array into a Jackson JsonNode.
JsonNode jsonNode = objectMapper.readTree(incomingArray.toString());
// Sets the Jackson node on the payload.
payload.set("array", jsonNode);

System.out.println(objectMapper.writeValueAsString(payload));
```

Comment: Actually using this method I am getting an exception `No serializer found for class org.json.JSONArray`. The problem is once I finished building the payload I have to serialize it. I think the correct answer is the previous one you give.

Comment: @MatteoZaccagnino: I didn't have any problems with ``putPOJO()``, but I've posted the ``readTree()`` implementation as well, in case others encounter a similar problem.

Comment: If you use `putPOJO()` and then try to serialize the created `ObjectNode`, you will get the exception above because jackson does not know how to serialize an instance of `JSONArray`. Anyway I marked your answer since it contains both soutions.